# How do I scale the regression coefficients to be between -1 and 1?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Say I have the following dataset

```
    Y   X1_v1   X1_v2
    5   3   54
   -2.3 2   32
    4   -6  12
    3   2   23
    88  4   22.4
   -230 0.3 55
```

If I run a simple regression of Y on X1_v1, I get the following results
[image]

Now, I run another regression of Y on X1_v2, I get the following:
[image]

What I want to do is to make the coefficients of X1_v1 to be "comparable" to that of X1_v2. To do this, I want to scale the coefficients of each regression so that the coefficient on X1_v1 and X1_v2 are between -1 and 1. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to rescale the regression coefficients? It's more common to rescale the predictors, because then the coefficients can be more interpretable - but that of course does not imply the estimates are in some specific interval.

Comment: Yes, I know generally the independent variables are rescaled, but in my case, I actually want the coefficients to be rescaled. For the actual data I am using, there are actually 2 different sets of data for X1 (the main variable of interest). So just consider a regression of Y on X1_v1 (the first set of data) and then Y on X1_v2 (the second set of data). I need the coefficient on X1 to be "comparable" between the 2 sets of data. That's why I want to rescale the coefficient. I’ve edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: It sounds very much more to me like you want to rescale your two predictors `X1_v1` and `X1_v2` so *they* are comparable (e.g., by scaling them both to have the same mean and standard deviation, or by scaling both to be between 0 and 1). Then you can compare the coefficient estimates of two regressions for the same outcome on the rescaled regressors, because then both coefficient estimates will have the *same* interpretation "estimated change in the response per 1 unit change in the (rescaled) predictor", and a 1 unit change in the rescaled predictor has the same meaning for both predictors.

Comment: Actually, I want to do things like take the average of the two coefficient estimates, you can imagine the data of X1_v1 is from one industry and X1_v2 is from another industry. So I can't simply take the average of the coefficients from just a simple regression of Y on X1_v1 and Y on X1_v2 because the impact of each industry is going to be different. That's why I want to scale the coefficients of each separate regression to be between -1 and 1, and then take averages. Or even purely from a statistical point of view, how would one rescale coefficients (as opposed to predictors)?

Comment: It still sounds to me like you should be thinking about rescaling regressors. Your last question is precisely my problem: in what way does it even make sense to rescale or transform parameter coefficient estimates? Of course, we can simply add 42 to each estimate, but then it does not have any connection to the model and the data on which it was fitted any more, so what is the point?

Comment: Okay, what about if the X1_v1 and X1_v2 are both dummy variables? You wouldn't be able to standardize a dummy variable right? So in that case, how would I make the coefficients "comparable" to each other?

Comment: If they are both dummies, then their coefficients are already comparable: in each case, they give the estimated increase in the response when the dummy is set.

Comment: Okay thanks! I get it now, that makes it much clearer.